# Apache rewrite Subdirectories URL Internally Redirect to Query String

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to make apache rewrite all links in the form :

```
host.com/links/<a>/<b>/<c>
```

such as :

```
host.com/links/1/2/3
```

To the form :

```
host.com/links/?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

I understand i need to add .htaccess with rewriting rules to `links` folder but dont really understand the syntax of the rewriting rules.

can any one help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [link](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewritePathInfo)

**The URL in the browser would be:**

```
host.com/links/1/2/3
```

**The actual page rendered by the server would be:**

```
host.com/links/?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

**Add to `.htaccess` this lines:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/links/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [PT]
```

> When you want to rewrite more complex URLs, you need to create more
>   complex regular expressions. Just about any pattern can be expressed
>   as a regular expression, if you break it down into small chunks. This
>   regular expression breaks down into just a few component parts, once
>   you get past staring at the seemingly random characters:

```
[^/]
```

> The above component is a character class containing a "not slash".
>   So, if we do ...

```
[^/]*
```

> that means "zero or more not-slash characters". In other words, we're
>   looking for everything between the slashes. There are two sets of
>   these, because we're looking for two blocks of things between slashes.
>   Armed with that little nugget of information, go look at the regular
>   expression again and see if it makes a little more sense.  As with the
>   earlier , I used the [PT] flag to indicate that the target URL was not
>   merely a file to be served, but was something that needed to be
>   handled. In this case, it's going to be a cgi-script handler. So
>   Apache passes the resulting URL through to that handler.

Answer (score 0):

The basci syntax of rewriting rule is to be followed like below.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(demo)\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(setup)/?$ http://www.%2/%1/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(demo)\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(xyz)/?$ http://www.%2/%1/web/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^demo\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(xyz)/?$ /web/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

For more informations about rewrite flags

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: can you be more specific? how do i change those lines you provided in my use case?